# how to register a java class if the static initializer isn't called till the class is referenced

Tags: java, factory-method, static-initializer

I've an interface implemented by classes that perform a file processing, say searching or whatever.

```
public interface FileProcessorInterface {

    public void processFile(String fileName);

}
```

Then i have a different implementation for each file type:

```
public class TxtProcessor implements FileProcessorInterface {

    @Override public void processFile(String fileName) { //do the work }

}
```

Thus i have the Utilizer of the processor, that has a method that allows for registering each class, something like this:

```
class Utilizer {

Map <String, Class> registered = new HashMap<>();

public void registerClass(String fileExt, Class clazz) {

    registered.put(fileExt, clazz);

}

public void processFile(String fileName) {

    //1) get the registered class from registered map (omitted because easy and not relevant)

    //2) create an instance of the class using reflection (omitted because easy and not relevant)
    FileProcessorInterface p = ....

    p.processFile(fileName);             

}
```

So far it's ok.

Now, i'm providing many implementations of my interface.

And i am tempted to provide each implementation class with a static initializer that register itself in the Utilizer, in the case of my previous TxtProcessor it would be:

```
class TxtProcessor implements FileProcessorInterface {

    //previous code

    static {
        Utilizer.registerClass("txt", TxtProcessor.class);
    }

}
```

The problem is that this static method will never be called because in the "statically reachable" code of the application there is no reference to my TxtProcessor class, since it is instantiated via reflection. So the jvm does not call the static initializer.

Say that i have two parts: the "generic code" that is the Utilizer and on the other side the implementations; it has to be thought as something provided dinamically and so it is not known by the Utilizer part. 

Infact the idea was exactly that each class would register itself leaving the Utilizer untouched.

It is hard for me conceiving a solution that does not put some form of 'knowledge' of the implementations on the Utilizer side (and that stays simple), just because of the problem of the static initializer not called. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) seems to be the best fit here. It's like geared to do this.

All you need is a small *static* block in `Utilizer` as

```
static {

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
                new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("path.to.all.processors.pkg"))
               .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner())
           );

    reflections.getSubTypesOf(path.to.all.processors.pkg.FileProcessor.class);
}
```

If you don't want a third-part dependency, just add a *FileProcessors.properties* file to your *classpath*

```
txt=path.to.all.processors.pkg.TxtProcessor
doc=path.to.all.processors.pkg.DocProcessor
pdf=path.to.all.processors.pkg.PdfProcessor
```

and then register all the listed classes from `Utilizer` as

```
static {
    Properties processors = new Properties();
    try {
        processors.load(Utilizer.class
                  .getResourceAsStream("FileProcessors.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (String ext : processors.stringPropertyNames()) {
        Utilizer.registerClass(ext, Class.forName(processors.getProperty(ext));
    }
}
```

This no longer requires a *static* block in every `FileProcessor` now.

Comment: How to you specify the package name (e.g. `"path.to.all.processors.pkg"`) when you don't know the package name? The code could be added to any project, and we can't have the developers needing to start editing code or configuration files. We need to be able to find all the relevant classes regardless.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library.  It allow you to find all the classes which implement an interface, have an annotation or extend a class.

Comment: +1, Reflections + an annotation seems like a good fit here, and avoids a config/resource file if it is not something that is really configurable.

Answer (score 3):

### You Could...

Use the same concept as JDBC does for loading it's drivers.  This would require you to use `Class#forName` to initialize the class when the program is first loaded.  While this does mean that the implementation is still dynamic from the point of view of your utility class, it is specified at run time by your application...

This gives you control over which implementation you might want to use

### You Could...

Use the same concept as something like `java.awt.Toolkit` uses when it initializes it's instance.

It basically looks up the resource (in this case a `System` property) and then loads the class dynamically using `Class`.

Personally, I normally look for a named resource (usually a properties file) and load a key from it.

Something like `getClass().getResource("/some/gloabl/configFile");`, which every implementation would need to provide.

Then, if available, read the properties file and find the key I'm after.

If more then one implementation is linked in though, there is no guarantee which one will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty: You can statically initialize your `Utilizer` in main() with correct association.
Better solution: externalize in a resource file association like

```
txt=path.to.package.TxProcessor
```

load it in `Utilizer` and load `FileProcessorInterface` implementors with `Class.forName()`

Comment: That does not work for purely thirdparty classes though

Answer (score 1):

you can force the static init by Class.forName(fqn, true, classLoader) or the short form Class.forName(fqn)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a registry file (for example, some XML file), that would contain the list of all classes you support :

```
<item type="txt">somepackage.TxtProcessor</item>
<item type="gif">somepackage.GIFProcessor</item>
...
```

Your `Utilizer` would load this file into its registry.